# Conditional Independence in Bayes Network

Tags: conditional-probability, graphical-model, bayesian-network

I have just started working through Michael Jordan's notes on [Probabilistic Graphical Models](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/prelims/chapter2.pdf) and seem to be stuck on the exercise on page 5. I summarize the question here:

Suppose $G = (V,E)$ is a DAG with $n$ nodes. Corresponding to each node $i \in V$, let $X_i$ be a random variable. Denote the set of random variables that belong to the parent nodes of $X_i$ by $X_{\pi_i}$. To each note $i$, let $f_i(x_i, x_{\pi_i})$ be a function that behaves like a pdf on $X_i$ conditioned on $X_{\pi_i}$. Let $p(x_1, \ldots , x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i, x_{\pi_i})$.

It can be shown that $p$ is a joint distribution on $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. Show that for every $i \in V, \> p(x_i \mid x_{\pi_i}) = f_i(x_i, x_{\pi_i})$. My idea for a proof was to use induction.

We can assume without loss in generality that the nodes are ordered topologically. Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
p(x_n \mid x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}) &= \frac{p(x_1, \ldots, x_n)}{p(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1})} \\
&= \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i, x_{\pi_i})}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i(x_i, x_{\pi_i})} \\
&= f_n(x_n, x_{\pi_n})
\end{align*}
$$

The last (EDIT:second*) equality follows from $x_n$ not being a parent of any node. Now, I wish to show that $p(x_n \mid x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}) = p(x_n \mid x_{\pi_n})$ and it is intuitive to me because no other node but the parents of $x_n$ have any sort of bearing on $p(x_n \mid x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}) = f_n(x_n, x_{\pi_n})$. But how would I show this formally? The rest of the result follows quickly from induction since we can just remove $x_n$ from the graph.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach won't work, because you haven't shown why $\tilde{p}(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}) =  \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i(x_i, x_{\pi_i})$ is the same as $p(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}) = \sum_{x_n} p(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. Both $p$ and $\tilde{p}$ are valid probability distributions, but it's not clear why the latter is necessarily the marginal of the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is quite horrendous but I think this is what you're looking for. I recommend trying this out on a small example of say 4 nodes to get a more concrete feeling for what's going on. I briefly explain the following equations at the bottom.
$$
\begin{align}
p(x_i | x_{\pi_i}) & = \frac{p(x_i, x_{\pi_i})}{p(x_{\pi_i})} \\
& = \frac{\sum_{ \{x_j \mid\ j \neq i, \ j \notin \pi_i \} } p(x_1, \dots, x_n)}{\sum_{ \{x_j \mid \ j \notin \pi_i \} } p(x_1, \dots, x_n)} \\
& = \frac{\sum_{ \{x_j \mid\ j \neq i, \ j \notin \pi_i \} } \prod_{k=1}^n f_k(x_k, x_{\pi_k}) }{\sum_{ \{x_j \mid \ j \notin \pi_i \} } \prod_{k=1}^n f_k(x_k, x_{\pi_k})} \\
& = \frac{f_i(x_i, x_{\pi_i}) \sum_{ \{x_j \mid\ j \neq i, \ j \notin \pi_i \} } \prod_{k\neq i} f_k(x_k, x_{\pi_k}) }{\sum_{ \{x_j \mid \ j \notin \pi_i \} } \prod_{k=1}^n f_k(x_k, x_{\pi_k})} \\
& = \frac{f_i(x_i, x_{\pi_i}) \phi(x_{\pi_i}) }{\phi(x_{\pi_i})} \\
& = f_i(x_i, x_{\pi_i}).
\end{align}
$$

1. Definition of conditional probability.
2. Marginalize the full joint distribution.
3. Definition of the joint distribution as the product of the factors.
4. Upper sum doesn't depend on $x_i$ or $x_{\pi_i}$ so we can factor out $f_i$.
5. Push the sums into the product one at a time and use the fact that each $f_k(x_k, x_{\pi_k})$ sums to one over $x_k$. In the end you're left with some function $\phi(x_{\pi_i})$. This happens in both the numerator and the denominator.
6. Cancel the $\phi$'s.